# Adding ingress and traefik to trino kubernetes deployment

Tags: kubernetes-helm, presto, trino

I have a trino cluster deployed on our on-promises k8s cluster.
I am trying to add a ingress rule on top of the clusterip that comes with trino out of the box on port 8080.

Adding this ingress declaration to my values.yaml its seems doesn´t work at all (we have similar applications and this usually works flawlessly)

```
ingress:
  enabled: true
annotations:
  kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
  external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/target: "traefik-east-ui.keu.mycompany.local"
hosts:
  - host: trino-dev.keu.mycompany.local
    paths: []
tls: []
```

Comment: what error you see when you deploy this?

Comment: i see no errors, it seems just ignore the ingress part